# Adding more than 50k records from report to campaign?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member, sales-cloud

I'm trying to add members to a campaign through lead/contact report and I'm hitting a snag since we deal with over 50k records at a time. Is Dataloader the only way of importing to the reports if there are over 50k at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Add to Campaign](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gp9rAAA) feature only supports up to 50,000 rows at once. If you can, filter the report to less than 50,000 so you can do it in batches, or use the data loader or another ETL tool (e.g. Informatica, Bulk API, etc).